# How to store Kendo dropdown value in variable using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, automation

```
//workflow
if (((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='chk_user_1']"))) != null)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\TestingScript\Search Package\UnitTestProject1\Logs\TestDPS.txt", "TestCase 3 is running successfully with Network" + Environment.NewLine);
}

else
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\TestingScript\Search Package\UnitTestProject1\Logs\TestDPS.txt", "TestCase 3 is running unsuccessfully with Network" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Above code is not working for me. Please help me out!

In log file, it is always displaying resulted data as below

> "TestCase 3 is running unsuccessfully with Network".

Comment: You need to store all elements with `id=chk_user_1` in a list then check the size of that list and then put your 'null' login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.id("chk_user_1"));
int size = all.size();

if (size != 0)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\TestingScript\Search Package\UnitTestProject1\Logs\TestDPS.txt", "TestCase 3 is running successfully with Network" + Environment.NewLine);
}

else
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"D:\TestingScript\Search Package\UnitTestProject1\Logs\TestDPS.txt", "TestCase 3 is running unsuccessfully with Network" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have not checked right now as I am out of town but I will check let you update soon. For now accepting this answer.